# View Pager is calling other fragments on startup and on swiping too

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-studio-3.0

> ## List of components in my app is following :

1. TabLayout - Tab1, Tab2, Tab3.
2. Fragments for Tabs - Tab1.xml & class, Tab2.xml & class, Tab3.xml & class.
3. ViewPager to show Fragments on tabs.

> **So, when app starts as i debugged the startup process, it works like following :**

1. it calls 'Tab1.class',
2. then it calls 'Tab2.class',

> **and when swipe from 'Tab1' to 'Tab2', it calls 'Tab3.class'.**
>
> **and when swipe from 'Tab2' to 'Tab3', it calls nothing.**

**on reverse swiping :**

> **when swipe from 'Tab3' to 'Tab2', it calls 'Tab1.class'.**
>
> **then when swipe from 'Tab2' to 'Tab1', it calls nothing.**

### Questions :

> 1. So, why does it do that?
> 2. How can i call ONLY 'tab1.class' when app starts on 'tab1'?
> 3. How can i call ONLY 'tab2.class' when i swipe from 'tab1' to 'tab2'?

---

## MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FixedTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    class FixedTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public FixedTabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return new Tab1();
                case 1:
                    return new Tab2();
                case 2:
                    return new Tab3();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
             return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.tab1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.tab2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.tab3);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="vwc.com.newconcept.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

> **Please Do Tell Solution For This Problem.**

Comment: `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` Have you tried setting this?

Comment: define *it calls 'TabX.class'* ... if it means creating fragment class instance then just think: how it would be posible to see both fragments on swipeing without creating them?

Comment: @Dipalis. No, i haven't. where should i put it? after viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);??

Comment: *ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);* - [Obviously, it doesn't change anything ...](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-dev/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#805) ... [also it is 1 by default](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-dev/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#88) ... nice example of [Million Monkeys Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)

Comment: @Dipalis. Thank you, but its not working.

Comment: @KeyurSureliya did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setOffscreenPageLimit

Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Hope this helps.

```
ViewPager mViewpager = (ViewPager)findView....
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: It initializes all 3 fragments on startups and after that it doesnt do that when i swipe.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` is intented to work in that way to avoid lag in `animations` while switching from one `fragment` to other `fragment`, it will load atleast one extra `fragment` alongside your Visible `Fragment` by which it makes sure there is scope to swipe.

because, while swiping view pager has capability to show two fragments simultaneously hence loads the one extra always, without two pages view pager is useless.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to initialize the components of tab1 when i m swiping from tab3 to tab2.

Comment: And it doesn't initialize the components of tab1 when i swipe from tab2.

Comment: It will be initialized already when you go to 2, it will just render its instance

Answer (score 0):

**For Refresh Fragment When Fragment Visible**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(this)
                .attach(this)
                .commit();
    }
}
```